# How can I get the number of speaker from a data frame by R

Tags: r

```
NUMBER      WEIGHT  DAILY-LANG RELIGION PROVINCE DISTRICT SUB_DISTRI
5           9.50    1167          1      11       01     010
6           9.50    1167          1      11       01     010
7           9.50    1167          1      11       01     010
8           10.30   4             2      33       071    220
9           10.10   6             1      61       8      170
```

[It is the data screen I have to find the daily_lang speaker numbers by each Sub_disrict](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQWPP.png)

Comment: Hello Samira, welcome to SO! If you expect to receive great answers then you need to elaborate more on your question. What have you tried so far? What exactly are you trying to achieve? The more detail you give us, the better answers you will receive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If thw colums `WEIGHT`, `DAILY-LANG`, `RELIGION`, `PROVINCE`, `DISTRICT` and `SUB_DISTRI` are `unique` for a speaker you can use `nrow` and `unique` to *get the number of speakers*.

```
nrow(unique(x))
#[1] 3
```

To get `DAILY-LANG` per `RELIGION`, `PROVINCE`, `DISTRICT` and `SUB_DISTRI` you can use `unique`, `split` and `interaction`:

```
y <- unique(x)
split(y$DAILY.LANG,
 interaction(y[c("RELIGION", "PROVINCE", "DISTRICT", "SUB_DISTRI")], drop=TRUE))
#$`1.11.1.10`
#[1] 1167
#
#$`1.61.8.170`
#[1] 6
#
#$`2.33.71.220`
#[1] 4
```

Or if `SUB_DISTRI` is already unique:

```
split(y$DAILY.LANG, y$SUB_DISTRI)
#$`10`
#[1] 1167
#
#$`170`
#[1] 6
#
#$`220`
#[1] 4
```

Data:

```
x <- structure(list(WEIGHT = c(9.5, 9.5, 9.5, 10.3, 10.1), DAILY.LANG = c(1167L, 
1167L, 1167L, 4L, 6L), RELIGION = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), PROVINCE = c(11L, 
11L, 11L, 33L, 61L), DISTRICT = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 71L, 8L), SUB_DISTRI = c(10L, 
10L, 10L, 220L, 170L)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```